# Getopt::Long with special character options (such as -%)

Tags: perl, optional-parameters

In a perl script, I am using `Getopt::Long` to parse the command line options when the script is called.

Now, I'd like to add an option `-%`:

```
die unless GetOptions (
    'x=i' => \my $x,
    'y:i' => \my $y,
    'z'   => \my $z,
    '%'   => \my $percent
);
```

yet, this results in `Error in option spec: "%"`. I could of course use `'pct' => \my $percent` instead of `'%'   => \my $percent` but I feel that the mnemonic value of `-%` is higher.

So, is it possible what I want, somehow with `Getopt::Long`? Or is there another option parser module that can do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with version 2.39 of `Getopt::Long` it's possible to characters as *aliases* that can't appear in Perl identifiers, so this is possible:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Getopt::Long;

my $percent = 100;

die unless GetOptions (
    'percent|%=f' => \$percent
);

print "\n  $percent%\n\n";
```

and then calling it

```
$ perl script.pl -% 5.4
```

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend against using the `-%` as an option... it's common practice to use any of the 62 available single chars or more verbose long options.

What would `-%` mean anyway ? Isn't it more or less a kind of '*unit*' in which another *argument* or *option* needs to be handled ?

```
draw_rect .... --opacity 0.75 # for a range between 0 .. 1.000
draw_rect .... --opacity 75 % # for a range between 0 .. 100.0

calculate_new_prices --discount 3.50 USD # for $3,50 less ?
calculate_new_prices --discount 3.50 EUR # for €3,50 less ?
calculate_new_prices --discount 3.50     # for  3,50 discount in  .... ?
calculate_new_prices --discount 35.0 %   # for 35.00 % offers ?
```

Getopt::Long knows how to handle options with multiple values, just pass it an ArrayRef:

```
GetOptions (
  ...
  'discount{1,2} => \@discount,
  ...
);
```

And if it is really a 'switch' then it probably means that something is 'relative' something else, simply use a more verbose option that says... "*it's relative*" instead of "*this is a percentage-sign*"....

```
my_script ....  --relative
```

---

Merry Christmas

Answer (score 2):

A workaround could be a simple preprocessing of `ARGV` replacing `%` with say `p`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

my $substitute_for_percent = 'p';
$_ =~ s/^-%/-$substitute_for_percent/ for (@ARGV);

GetOptions (
    'z'   => \my $z,
     $substitute_for_percent   => \my $percent
) or die;
```